# Is there a way to add a digital signature to visio? Can I use VBA to display my digital signature on my Visio form?

Tags: digital-signature, visio

I use Microsoft Visio for my work application. Each form I complete has to be digitally signed. Currently, I have to convert each of those files to PDF to digitally sign. I would like to be able to input a digital signature directly into visio. The legal requirement for my digital signature must contain:

(a) A statement or other indication that the document or form was digitally signed.
(b) Name of the individual who digitally signed the document or form.
(c) Certificate policy identifier associated with the certificate of the individual who digitally signed the document or form.
(d) Date and time document was signed.

I convert the files to a PDF, and use Adobe to input the digital signatures using a certificate. This fulfills my requirements. However, There are froms which require multiple signatures. Additionally, I have to provide these forms to multiple people, some of who are not computer literate. I need a way for them to just be able to click and sign the Visio Form.

My problem is in using Visio. In Microsoft Word and Excel I can apply digital signatures. What Visio has which is crucial to my work is the ability to develop stencils which have shapes that can be drug and dropped into the form.

I would like to be able to click on a field in visio, and put a digital signature directly onto that form. Either and Add-on or VBA scripts would be acceptable methods to complete this, if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only aspects of Visio that can have a digital signing certificate applied are documents that contain VBA macros (.VSDM, .VSSM and .VSTM files) and Visio add-ons (.EXE amd .VSL (.DLL) files). Forms embedded within Visio files cannot be separately signed. When exported to PDF format any digital signing is not carried over.